# How to make a batch file that will make a batch file that does 2 commands

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that will create another batch file and that second batch file inside will have 2 commands in it so if the second batch file is activated it does those 2 things. I have the basic idea, I can create a batch file that makes another batch file

```
echo echo ^> b.bat > a.bat
```

Now I want to make it so I can launch a batch file that will have AT LEAST 2 commands in it, this is what I have.

```
echo echo ^> start ^ echo start ^ > z.bat
```

Pretty much I need to know how to make an enter so It will launch the second start command. yes I know where some of the carrots are, are wrong. I know you can make things like this with other script types but I want to stay in batch.

Sorry if the coding it not all perfect im still learning.

Comment: `( echo echo Command one & echo echo Command two ) > z.bat`

Comment: Instead of editing your question, please write the answer in the Answer section below.

Comment: basically I guess, you need to know the difference between `>` and `>>` ("(over)write" and "append")

Answer (score 0):

To make a batch file that will generate a batch file with an unlimited amount of commands inside can be done with this line of code in a bat file.

```
echo^ start co1 ^| start co2 ^| start co3 ^| start co4 >aa.bat
```

of corse change the "start co1-co4" to add more just do ^| to the front as you can see that I did. You can also change aa to your name you want it to have.

Comment: while this might work in this special case for you, it will doom you in other cases. The `|` pipes the output of the first command as input for the second one. Use `&` to concatenate two commands, like Aacini showed you or use "append" (`>>`) to add more lines.